# how to check if a connection is valid in Airflow UI?

Tags: mysql, connection, airflow

I'm using Airflow 1.10.10,
I have triggered a DAG to run using the Air Flow UI,
and I'm getting this error about MySql connection ( i see it in 'view log' )

```
ERROR - (2006, "Unknown MySQL server host 'http://nowapi1.cvxmgb2uxecn.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com/' (-3)")
```

- other connections that I have are valid and working successfully.
  is there a way to validate the connection using the Air Flow UI?
  / what should i check next?

Thanks!

Comment: I dont see any option on airflow ui side. Your choice now is to validate the connection on your instance before you add. I do see there is a jira related to this. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2998 . This is still open.

Comment: Hey @hopeIsTheonlyWeapon, 
that what I thought, thank you!

Comment: If this answers your question can I post it as an answer and can you kindly accept it as well ?

Comment: hey,  hopeIsTheonlyWeapon, yes, sure.

Answer (score 2):

This is great option to have.

But with current airflow UI before you add the connection you can check if the port is accessible to your airflow instance is the only option I see.

This can be done using

```
telnet <host> <port>
nc
```

I do see a AIRFLOW jira regarding this but its still open. May be take a look later.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2998

Answer (score 1):

In newer Airflow versions and assuming provider hook support it, you test the connection with the UI:

Example:

[image]

Connections that don't support this will be shown as hidden button:
[image]

**Note:** It's very important to check the connection docs for the provider you are testing. This is to avoid cases where the test passes but the connection doesn't actually work. The test function may run different logic than what you expect. An example for that would be the [Amazon Web Service connection](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-amazon/stable/connections/aws.html).

> The Amazon Web Services Connection can be tested in the UI/API or by
> calling test_connection(), it is important to correctly interpret the
> result of this test. During this test components of Amazon Provider
> invoke AWS Security Token Service API GetCallerIdentity. This service
> can only check if your credentials are valid. Unfortunately it is not
> possible to validate if credentials have access to specific AWS
> service or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the connection option by clicking `Admin` in Airflow UI. You will find one `connection` option there. Once you will click on `connection` option, you will see all your connections there. You can click on the edit option of the individual to check the info.

Comment: thanks @Ankur Ranjan,
i'm aware of this option, the issue is Testing the connection itself using the Air Flow UI